# How to extract and recognize the vehicle plate number with Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr, python-tesseract

I have tried using pytesseract in collaboration with PIL to identify the vehicle registration number from the number plate image. But am not able to get the text from these images.

the code:

```
 from PIL import Image
 from pytesseract import image_to_string

 img= Image.open('D://carimage1')
 text = image_to_string(img)
 print(text)
```

While this is working for normal scanned documents, it is not working for vehicle number plates.

Sample Image 1

[image]

Sample image 2

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a rough idea on how you can solve your problem. You can build on top of it. You need to extract the number plate from the image and then send the image to your tesseract. Read the code comments to understand what I am trying to do.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pytesseract
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('/home/muthu/Documents/3r9OQ.jpg')
#convert my image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#perform adaptive threshold so that I can extract proper contours from the image
#need this to extract the name plate from the image. 
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,1,2)

#once I have the contours list, i need to find the contours which form rectangles.
#the contours can be approximated to minimum polygons, polygons of size 4 are probably rectangles
largest_rectangle = [0,0]
for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    if len(approx)==4: #polygons with 4 points is what I need.
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area > largest_rectangle[0]:
            #find the polygon which has the largest size.
            largest_rectangle = [cv2.contourArea(cnt), cnt, approx]

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(largest_rectangle[1])
#crop the rectangle to get the number plate.
roi=img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
#cv2.drawContours(img,[largest_rectangle[1]],0,(0,0,255),-1)
plt.imshow(roi, cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()
```

The output is the number plate as attached below:

[image]

Now pass this cropped image into your tesseract.

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(roi)
print text
```

I get the below output for the sample image you shared.

[image]

The parsing will be more accurate if you perspective transform your number plate image to the bounding box rectangle and also remove the extra borders around. Let me know if you need help with that too.

The code above doesn't work for second image if used as it is, because I am filtering the search to polygons with 4 sides. Hope you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks in advance, can you please guide what should be change for first image or any other image ?

Answer (score 2):

This one works only for the [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcjXJ.jpg):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import pytesseract

img = Image.open('TcjXJ.jpg')
img2 = img.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
pixels = img2.load()
width, height = img2.size
x_ = []
y_ = []
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        if pixels[x, y] == (255, 255, 255):
            x_.append(x)
            y_.append(y)

img = img.crop((min(x_), min(y_),  max(x_), max(y_)))
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
print(text)
```

You've got on output:

```
TN 99 F 2378
```

Comment: I am getting TNSSF 2378

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [OpenVINO engine](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/use-an-inference-engine-api-in-python-to-deploy-the-openvino-toolkit), it contains [pretrained model and sample](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-IE-Samples#security-barrier-camera) for plate detection and recognition.
2. [OpenALPR](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/wiki/Integrating-OpenALPR) for Python.

Comment: will try these and let you know. Nuzhny, did you tried with these libraries before ?

Comment: Yes, but with C++ API